# aspose cell time format

Tags: c#, aspose

I try to set cell format using AsposeCell API (C#):

```
var cell = worksheet.Cells[i, j];
Style style = cell.GetStyle();
style.Number = 21;
cell.SetStyle(style);

var time = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 3);
cell.PutValue(time);
```

This cell is displayed correctly, but has format: "all formats" (not "Time"). That is to say, `style` property did not work. What's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Try asking on the [Aspose Cells Support forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells). They are usually really quick to answer.

Comment: Magnus, thank you for advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to kindly convert TimeSpan string to proper data type when inputting into the cell via Aspose.Cells API.

```
cell.PutValue(time.ToString(), true); //true specifies that the data will be converted to proper data type.
```

It works now. May to use these cells as time cells (for example, to count sum or average)

Comment: You did it well as the inserted data should be (converted) into respective data type to apply formatting/style properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting value first, then setting style.

```
var cell = worksheet.Cells[i, j];

var time = new TimeSpan(1, 2, 3);
cell.PutValue(time);

Style style = cell.GetStyle();
style.Number = 21;
cell.SetStyle(style);
```

If not working, use `style.Custom` instead.

```
style.Custom = "h:mm:ss";
```

Comment: Thank's for answer, but it is all the same: cell has format "all formats"